# What is the difference between List<List<?>> and List<? extends List<?>>

Tags: java, generics

The two seem to give the same result. What am I missing? Thanks.

```
List<List<?>>
    <==> List<List<? extends Object>>
    <==> List<List<Number>>  **(for example)**

List<? extends List<?>>
    <==> List<? extends List<? extends Object>>
    <==> List<? extends List<Number>>  **(for example)**
    <==> List<List<Number>>  **(List<Number> is a subtype of ? extends List<Number>**
```

Comment: Hint - try passing an object of type `List<LinkedList<Object>>` into a method that takes a parameter of type `List<List<?>>`. Then try passing the same type into a method that takes a parameter of type `List<? extends List<?>>`.

Comment: Try it; what types can you successfully add to that second list?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you have a list of a list of something.

In the second case, you have a list of something that extends a list of something.

In your example, the second part of code works because, indeed, a `List<number>` , in it's own way, extends `List<?>`. You can read more about polymorphism to learn why.

Bellow is an example on what you can do with that.

```
class MyList<T> extends List<T> {}

List<List<?>> someVariable = Arrays.asList(new MyList(), new MyList()); // won't work.

List<? extends List<?>> someOtherVariable = Arrays.asList(new MyList(), new MyList()); // will work.
```

This is a very basic example but it shows the difference between the two.